# block grid with different height DIV's

Tags: javascript, html, css

I found many solutions on the internet about different height image grids but i'm trying to make an easy div grid with different heights.

**See my JSfiddle here:**
http://jsfiddle.net/44ffoafu/1/
*(I want the blocks to float into the empty spaces)*

I already tried adding one of the following display tags to the div's but they don't work.

```
display:inline;
display:inline-block;
display:block;
display:table-cell;
```

I know of javascripts like FreeWall and Masonry but i'm looking for an easier way and a way that works with percentages. A CSS only solution is what i'm looking for but if someone has a small javascript hack, please let me know too!

Answer (score 0):

you can try this one:
only use pure CSS : `column-count` & `column-gap`.

firstly: 
change your html like this one:

```
    <div class='wrapper'>
      <div class="block" id="one"></div>
      <div class="block" id="two"></div>
      <div class="block" id="three"></div>
      <div class="block" id="four"></div>
      <div class="block" id="five"></div>
      <div class="block" id="six"></div>
      <div class="block" id="seven"></div>
      <div class="block" id="eight"></div>
      <div class="block" id="nine"></div>
      <div class="block" id="ten"></div>
      <div class="block" id="eleven"></div>
      <div class="block" id="twelf"></div>
      <div class="block" id="thirteen"></div>
   </div>
```

and then change your css code like this:

```
.wrapper {
    -moz-column-count: 4;
    -moz-column-gap: 5px;
    -webkit-column-count: 4;
    -webkit-column-gap: 5px;
    column-count: 4;
    column-gap: 5px;
}
.block{
    width:100%;
    display:inline-block;
    margin-bottom: 0px;
    margin-top:0px;
}
#one {
    height:150px;
    background:#ff0000;
}
#two {
    height:150px;
    background:#00ff00;
}
#three {
    height:300px;
    background:#0000ff;
}
#four {
    height:150px;
    background:#000000;
}
#five {
    height:150px;
    background:#ff0000;
}
```

refresh your browser.
it's work fine for me.

Comment: thank you for your answer, it worked half but not entirely how I had in mind.. this solution mixes the different divs and its not possible anymore to have one div more width then another.. http://jsfiddle.net/44ffoafu/2/